# C++ inline assembly function not working properly

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I get a different return value each time, so I'm doing something wrong. If I replace the **add** with a basic **inc**, it returns correctly.

Here is the code.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Add ( int _Number1, int _Number2 );

int main ( int _ArgumentCount, char * _Arguments[] )
{
    int nInput, nOutput;

    nOutput = Add ( 1, 1 );

    cout << "1 + 1 = " << nOutput << endl;
    cin >> nInput;

    return 0;
}

__declspec ( naked ) int Add ( int _Number1, int _Number2 )
{
    __asm   xor eax, eax
    __asm   mov eax, _Number1
    __asm   add eax, _Number2
    __asm   ret
}
```

**Here is the new, working code:**

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Add ( int Number1, int Number2 );

int main ( int ArgumentCount, char * Arguments[] )
{
    int nInput, nOutput;

    nOutput = Add ( 1, 1 );

    cout << "1 + 1 = " << nOutput << endl;
    cin >> nInput;

    return 0;
}

int Add ( int Number1, int Number2 )
{
    __asm   mov eax, Number1
    __asm   add eax, Number2
}
```

Comment: How do you know `_Number1` isn't `eax`?  The compiler is allowed to call functions with their arguments in registers.   I think your problem is that you haven't made any effort to avoid stepping on the compiler's toes by declaring your used registers, etc.  Take a look at your program disassembly for proof.

Comment: Why are you using `__declspec(naked)`? Are you sure you need to do that? What happens if you don't?

Comment: @Borealid - This is my first attempt, not really sure what I'm doing. I thought EAX was reserved for return values, which registers should I use?

@Greg - Had some compilation problems without it. Searched google, and a guy on a forum said to use the naked declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__declspec (naked)` means the function is created without any prolog or epilog code -- so if you want to access formal parameters, you need to write prolog code of your own to give you access to them. Your `xor` is also accomplish nothing, since you immediately overwrite eax with another value. Also note that any identifier starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved, so your code had undefined behavior. Try rewriting your function as:

```
int Add ( int number1, int number2 )
{
    __asm   mov eax, number1
    __asm   add eax, number2
}
```

or else write the code to access the parameters on the stack without depending on a prolog:

```
__declspec (naked) int Add2(int number1, int number2) { 
    _asm mov eax, [esp+4]
    _asm add eax, [esp+8]
    _asm ret
}
```

I didn't check, but I'd guess your original code was trying to load the parameters from [ebp+8] and [ebp+12]. This depends on the normal prolog code:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

...which your `__declspec (naked)` specifically told the compiler *not* to generate.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I admit, when it didn't compile, and I found the naked "solution", I didn't even read into it. Very lazy of me.

I also had no idea about the reserved names. Thanks a bunch, I've got it working now.